# How to test RESTful call to database without seeding data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have a dropdown box that is populated using data from the database (via Angular).

I am trying to test it with Capybara and Poltergeist using:

```
        select('San Francisco', from: "user_region")
```

As the test database starts with a clean DB, the San Francisco option in the database cannot be loaded. How should I populate the dropdown box if I have no DB?

One idea is to run the db:seed from seed.rb but I'd rather rely on less assumptions when I run my tests. Is there a way to use something like Factory Girl?

Thanks,

Comment: How about using FactoryGirl to create the option in the test setup?

Comment: Can you elaborate? thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Example, when you have the following capybara test case, use the background block to setup the data you need for your testing

```
feature "Signing in" do   
  background do
    Option.create(:name => "San Francisco", :value => "something") #you could also use FactoryGirl.create(:option)   
  end

  scenario "Signing in with correct credentials" do
    visit '/sessions/new'
    fill_in 'Login', :with => 'user@example.com'
    fill_in 'Password', :with => 'caplin'
    click_link 'Sign in'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Success'
  end 
end
```

Here is the [link for factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) if you don't know about it already. It comes very handy in setting up data for all kinds of tests.